# Component based coding (with Angular 7)

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies, components

I'm a big fan of reusable component building and have yet to figure out the correct way of doing so. Is it even possible to build standalone components that can just be thrown into other Angular applications, even if they have dependencies like Bootstrap or jQuery?

Example:
I downloaded a beautiful website template which I'm trying to modify and "break apart" for later reusage of single sections of the website. It is a single page website, and let's say I want to isolate the "Contact Us" section. This section fades in with an animation as soon you scroll to it. It has Bootstrap 3 classes in its HTML component, and the animation comes from wowJS which is imported in the index.html file of the angular app.

Now if I would include this section component into another project, theres no way to tell which dependencies it has (unless you of course recognize the Bootstrap 3 and wowJS syntaxes in the HTML component). Also another big problem: even if I find a way to isolate the component completely from the rest of the website, then after combining several components to a new website, all the common dependencies would load multiple times. I guess that if you use Angular-only tools then it's well possible to build custom, completely standalone reusable components. But with external dependencies, all I can do is to include a readme file in every component and list the dependencies?

I googled a lot on this topic and I didn't really find the answers I'm looking for. Hope someone can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you are right. In order to make reusable and standalone angular components you should use angular-tools which handles the dependencies.

But as per your example you have to manage dependencies manually. Or if you can separate concerns like header or nav-bar you can create a npm package compatible with angular applications and having their own packag.json, maintaining dependecies.
Here is a package: [angular-package-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-package-builder)

Comment: Thank you. I read a very long tutorial about this after your post, and this seems to come close to what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible to build standalone components that can just be thrown into other Angular applications, even if they have dependencies like Bootstrap or jQuery?

Technically, yes. For example, PrimeNG is an Angular UI library, and comes with some component options for charting. Those components in turn, use ChartsJS, another third party library, which you do not have to manually install, or even maintain. PrimeNG takes care of its own dependencies.

> ... and let's say I want to isolate the "Contact Us" section... Now if I would include this section component into another project, theres no way to tell which dependencies it has..

This is most likely the source of your confusion. It sounds like, in the process of taking things apart, you're treating each component as a single 'module', with its own dependencies. You're taking a component thats subject to already defined rules (needs bootstrap, etc) and trying to make it into a standalone module. A typical UI kit is a set of 'related' components and attempts to consolidate dependencies as much as possible so all of the components share needs. What Im trying to say is, right now you're working backwards, starting from the end result and trying to derive commonalities.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I tried to isolate components to not worry about adding all the dependecies of each component into the index.html file. I think I understand a little better why this is not as easy as I thought.